# Using Stanford classifier for character recognition

Tags: ocr, stanford-nlp, maxent

I am working on an OCR related android app and I need to use multivariate logistic regressions for the classification of alphabets. My question is that that can I use Stanford classifier(http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml) for character recognition? If it can train on a dataset of images? And if I can't then please suggest me a JAVA library for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Great minds think alike. I was wondering the same thing. Specifically for OCR.
Even though it's almost a year after you asked your question.

It sounds simple enough; all you would need to do is normalize each character into a 5x7 array (or maybe 64x128), and then classify into the 26 upper and 26 lower case characters; plus 10 digits and 31 punctuation glyphs on a keyboard... Seems doable. Maybe when I get a round tuit...

It turns out that there is a Java library for OCR https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/ and it's called Java OCR (surprise! :-) ). The only problem is that:
1. It doesn't work out of the box. It needs to be trained.
2. The documentation isn't very good.
3. People have had trouble getting it to work.

Good luck.

Comment: Already accomplished it using tesseract as well as Google Mobile Vision api :) thank you :)